# MongoDB troubleshooting on Windows (C#) (What to do?)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have trouble with MongoDB on Windows 7 (32 bit). I make some tests with adding/deleting data. So after some time (i do not know how much, maybe 10 minutes of non-stopping requests) MongoDB server still works but not answers! From console shell I tried command "show collections", but it stucks! The size of storage at this moment was only 160 MBs. This trouble was yesterday and it was before not always, but from time to time. And only after restarting MongoDB works fine before next such trouble. Help me please what to check, profile, etc. Finally MongoDB will work on 64 bit machines, but I am afraid, because I do not want to restart it every 10-60 minutes!!! I use official C# driver.

Thank you for advices!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

**Closed**

Comment: lol! while I wrote this question MongoDB stucked again!:D

Comment: What version of mongodb? Also post please code that start mongodb.

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5 ;)

Comment: I am also now using 1.6.5 in both 32bit(at home) and 64bit(at work) and never run into the same problem. Also is there any errors?

Comment: Log file is empty without any errors))) but I run Mongo without --quiet flag)))

Comment: Okay, than what does 'it stucks' mean? Query return nothing? Have you tried run the same query from c# code?

Comment: At some time MongoDB does not return anything before I restart it))) And it happening from C# and from shell. I think that I must more carefully make connections to it and disconnections. Maybe table of connections on MongoDB's side are full. Thank you Bugai13 for trying to help me, but I think I must recheck my source code. Please do not spend a lot of time on me;) I'll back after I'll have more details;))

Comment: I made separate question;) Please check it;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352018/mongodb-c-connections-disconnections-official-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could watch some information about working mongodb on  ip + 1000), so by default is http://localhost:28017.

Check amount of opened connections to mongo server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is causing your problem, but the points that spring to mind are:

1. are you using an older version of MongoDB? Try the latest release.
2. are you using the latest version of the driver? If not, try that.
3. running mongoDB on 32bit is not at all ideal. I would only run it on 64bit - and have done so for a few months now without any similar problems.
4. is anything appearing the logs, any errors?
5. if nothing above helps, best thing to do is post it on the MongoDB forums as you'll get more help there